# Validate okta access token in Spring boot Spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, access-token, okta

I am trying to validate the okta token in spring-security which I am getting from the UI. From okta website I got the below  config to validate the tokens

```
AccessTokenVerifier jwtVerifier = JwtVerifiers.accessTokenVerifierBuilder()
    .setIssuer("https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default")
    .setAudience("api://default")                // defaults to 'api://default'
    .setConnectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) // defaults to 1s
    .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))       // defaults to 1s
    .build();
```

and it works as well, but I am not able to call the above from spring-security configuration please help me to write the spring-security config to validate jwt token in spring security

Application details:
Springboot2.5

Mycode: in springsecurity config (which has error and doesnot work)

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        
        httpSecurity.headers()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                .includeSubDomains(true)
                .maxAgeInSeconds(63072000);
        
        httpSecurity.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                //.permitAll()
                .authenticated()
                .and().oauth2ResourceServer() .jwt()
                  .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())
                  .validator(oktaAccessTokenValidator());

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm gonna make some promotion for [my starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) again.

You should have a look at the [pro and cons](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#drawbacks) of using such an additional starter. This section also contains links to tutorials with directions to write the conf yourself (without my starter).

With my starter, all you'll need will be:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <!-- this replaces the libs from Okta -->
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default
          # optional: adds an audience validator to JWT decoder
          aud: api://default
          authorities:
          # you may add as many JSON path as you need to use as source for Spring authorities
          # you may also apply basic transformation (prefix and case) if needed
          - path: $.groups
        resourceserver:
          permit-all:
          # what is listed here is accessible to anonymous
          - "/public/**"
          cors:
          # Optional CORS configuration
          - path: /**
            allowed-origin-patterns: http://localhost:4200
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

Nothing about security omitted. You don't even need to provide a `SecurityFilterChain`, token verifier, JWT decoder, authentication converter, authentication manager or whatever. The best thing being its gonna work with any other OpenID provider (Auth0, Keycloak, Amazon Cognito, spring-authorization-server, etc.): all you'd have to change would be JSON path to the private claims to use as authorities source.

If you later need an OAuth2 client instead or in addition to your resource server, my starter is adapted too and the difference in properties is explained in the [main README](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#1-spring-boot-starter).